# ¿Cómo escribir en un fichero una cadena formateada C#?

Tags: c#

Buenas a todos y a todas. Soy nuevo en el mundillo de C# y tengo una duda.

Estoy realizando una práctica relacionada con la ficha de personajes de rol.

La práctica me pide que cree un personaje y que gestione esos datos para guardarlos en un fichero de texto.

Resumo lo que tengo:

Form1 con todos los campos a rellenar y funciones.

Clase personaje que crea y gestiona los datos para moverlos al fichero.
Una vez se rellenan los datos, pulsamos en el botón de guardar que contiene el siguiente código:

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Pre requisitos
        if (obtenerNombre() == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor, introduzca un nombre");
        }
        if (numPuntos == 0)
        {
            //Al pulsar en el boton de guardar, creamos el personaje y lo pasamos al fichero
            String[] caracteristicas = new String[6];
            String[] mochila = new String[16];
            String[] habilidades = new String[6];
            Personaje personaje = new Personaje(obtenerNombre(), recogerSexo(), recogerRaza(), obtenerProfesion(), obtenerEspecialidad());
            //Vamos recogiendo los datos restantes
            //Comenzamos por las caracteristicas

            caracteristicas[0] = numbVida.Text.ToString();
            caracteristicas[1] = numbMana.Text.ToString();
            caracteristicas[2] = numbAD.Text.ToString();
            caracteristicas[3] = numbDef.Text.ToString();
            caracteristicas[4] = numbSpeed.Text.ToString();
            caracteristicas[5] = numbRegen.Text.ToString();

            personaje.setCaracteristicas(caracteristicas);
            //rellenamos la mochila
            mochila[0] = chkItem1.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[1] = chkItem2.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[2] = chkItem3.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[3] = chkItem4.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[4] = chkItem5.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[5] = chkItem6.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[6] = chkItem7.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[7] = chkItem8.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[8] = chkItem9.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[9] = chkItem10.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[10] = chkItem11.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[11] = chkItem12.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[12] = chkItem13.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[13] = chkItem14.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[14] = chkItem15.Checked.ToString();
            mochila[15] = chkItem16.Checked.ToString();

            personaje.setMochila(mochila);
            //rellenamos las habilidades
            habilidades[0] = numDeterminacion.Text.ToString();
            habilidades[1] = numJusticia.Text.ToString();
            habilidades[2] = numValor.Text.ToString();
            habilidades[3] = numSabiduria.Text.ToString();
            habilidades[4] = numEscudo.Text.ToString();
            habilidades[5] = numMasacre.Text.ToString();

            personaje.setHabilidades(habilidades);

            //hacemos el toString para pasarlo a un archivo
            personaje.ToString();
            personaje.ToFile();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debe poner los puntos en las caracteristicas");
        }


    }
```

Este código crea un objeto de la clase personajes:

```
    class Personaje
{
    //Variables
    private String[] habilidades;
    private String[] caracteristicas;
    private String[] mochila;
    private String nombre;
    private String raza;
    private String sexo;
    private String profesion;
    private String especialidad;
    private String cadenaPersonaje;

    //Constructor
    public Personaje(String nombrePJ, String sexoPJ, String razaPJ, String profesionPJ, String especialidadPJ) {
        nombre = nombrePJ;
        sexo = sexoPJ;
        raza = razaPJ;
        profesion = profesionPJ;
        especialidad = especialidadPJ;
    }

    public string[] getHabilidades()
    {
        return habilidades;
    }

    public void setHabilidades(String[] skills)
    {
        habilidades = skills;
    }
    public string[] getMochila()
    {
        return mochila;
    }

    public void setMochila(String[] inventory)
    {
        mochila = inventory;
    }
    public string[] getCaracteristicas()
    {
        return caracteristicas;
    }

    public void setCaracteristicas(String[] caracts)
    {
        caracteristicas = caracts;
    }
    public void toString()
    {
        cadenaPersonaje = "";
        String delimitador = " | ";
        //vamos agregando los campos
        cadenaPersonaje += nombre + delimitador + sexo + delimitador + profesion + delimitador + especialidad + delimitador;
        //creamos los bucles para  recorrer los arrays
        for (int i = 0; i < caracteristicas.Length; i++)
        {
            cadenaPersonaje += caracteristicas[i] + delimitador;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < mochila.Length; j++)
        {
            cadenaPersonaje += mochila[j] + delimitador;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < habilidades.Length; k++)
        {
            cadenaPersonaje += habilidades[k] + delimitador;
        }

    }
    public String getCadena()
    {
        return cadenaPersonaje;
    }
    public void ToFile()
    {
        //pasamos todo al archivo
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"dataFiles/Hoja.txt",true);
        file.WriteLine(cadenaPersonaje);
        file.Close();

    }
}
```

El problema es el siguiente:

**Me encuentra el fichero pero no me escribe nada**. Es posible que el método toString esté mal.

¿Alguien sabe por qué no me escribe en el fichero?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Estás llamando a toString o a ToString?

Comment: he creado una funcion toString en la clase Personaje.

Comment: Te recomiendo convertir tu ejemplo a un [mcve] para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Añade un Debug.writeLine(cadenaPersonaje) al final de toString() para comprobar que la variable no esté vacía.
En [este](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8bh11f1k.aspx) enlace, utilizan contrabarra ( '\' ) para la ruta del fichero.

Comment: Al final de tu método btnGuardar_click estás llamando a personaje.ToString(). "ToString" es un método heredado de object y por eso no te da ningún error, pero tú tienes un método "toString" que es el que crea "cadenaPersonaje". El caso es que a ese método no le llamas nunca porque estás llamando a "ToString" y por tanto "cadenaPersonaje" no se rellena y por eso nunca se graba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No encuentra nada en el fichero porque estás escribiendo una cadena vacía en él. En primer lugar, deberías sobreescribir el método `ToString()` heredado de object en la clase `Personaje`. Tú estás inventándote un nuevo método `toString()` al cual ni siquiera estás invocando en el manejador de eventos del botón.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    cadenaPersonaje = "";
    String delimitador = " | ";
    //vamos agregando los campos
    cadenaPersonaje += nombre + delimitador + sexo + delimitador + profesion + delimitador + especialidad + delimitador;
    //creamos los bucles para  recorrer los arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < caracteristicas.Length; i++)
    {
        cadenaPersonaje += caracteristicas[i] + delimitador;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < mochila.Length; j++)
    {
        cadenaPersonaje += mochila[j] + delimitador;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < habilidades.Length; k++)
    {
        cadenaPersonaje += habilidades[k] + delimitador;
    }    
    return cadenaPersonaje;
}
```

En el método `ToFile()` llamaría a `ToString()` y no afuera, como lo estás haciendo tú.

```
public void ToFile()
{
    //pasamos todo al archivo
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"dataFiles/Hoja.txt",true);
    file.WriteLine(ToString());
    file.Close();
}
```

Y por último, en el manejador de eventos del botón sólo te haría falta un `personaje.ToFile()` sin llamar previamente a `ToString()`.

Comment: Tienes Razón. El problema era que había llamado al ToString de la clase String en vez de el de la clase Personaje. Muchas gracias.